# Issues when using Protractor with PhantomJS

Tags: protractor

We start a new AngularJS project and we plan to use protractor with PhantomJS for our e2e front end tests.
We noticed that the Protractor team  recommend against using PhantomJS for tests with Protractor 
because there are many reported issues with PhantomJS crashing and behaving differently from real browsers.

1 - Is this still the case and PhantomJS still having issues with Protractor?

2 - We would like to know what we could use instead of PhantomJS ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a few problems usng protractor myself. Most of them were related to timeout because "somethng" didnt load.

I found some configs that helped a lot (put them on protractor.conf.js)

```
  allScriptsTimeout: 20000, restartBrowserBetweenTests: true, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes that is still the case, it's generally better to run e2e tests in a non-headless browser.  You can still use PhantomJS if you really want too, but as stated there are many reported problems and it probably won't be stable.

2) This is opinionated, but naturally I think Chrome is typically the most stable browser (both in general and specifically for Protractor since they're both made by Google).  Though you shouldn't have many issues with other real browsers either i.e. Firefox, ie11, Safari etc.

Comment: Thank you for your response